# Why I am bounced from the Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
USER root
WORKDIR /usr/share/elasticsearch/

ENV ES_HOSTNAME elasticsearch
ENV ES_PORT 9200

RUN chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch data
# install security plugin

RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install -b com.floragunn:search-guard-5:5.5.2-16
COPY ./safe-guard/install_demo_configuration.sh plugins/search-guard-5/tools/

COPY ./safe-guard/init-sgadmin.sh plugins/search-guard-5/tools/
RUN chmod +x plugins/search-guard-5/tools/init-sgadmin.sh

ADD ./run.sh .
RUN chmod +x run.sh


RUN chmod +x plugins/search-guard-5/tools/install_demo_configuration.sh

RUN ./plugins/search-guard-5/tools/install_demo_configuration.sh -y

RUN chmod +x sgadmin_demo.sh

RUN  yum install tree -y

#RUN curl -k -u admin:admin https://localhost:9200/_searchguard/authinfo

RUN usermod -aG wheel elasticsearch


USER elasticsearch

EXPOSE 9200

#ENTRYPOINT ["nohup",  "./run.sh", "&"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/run.sh"]

#CMD ["echo", "hello"]
```

Once I add either CMD or Entrypoint - "Container is exited with code 0"

```
#!/bin/bash

exec $@
```

If I comment ENTRYPOINT or CMD - all is great.

What I am doing wrong???

Comment: because container exits when execution within is done.

Comment: Thank you, @alex-karshin. What I suppose to do if I need to run sgadmin_demo.sh after ES comes up, I would say 10-15 seconds later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at official [5.6.9 elasticsearch Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/a83e1837684d580e66f31cb01940ac1b99eef3aa/5/Dockerfile), you will see the following at the bottom:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

If you do not know the difference between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564990/3324556).

What you're doing is you're overwriting those two instructions with something else. What you really need is to extend `CMD`. What I usually do in my images, I create an `sh` script and combine different things I need and then indicate the script for `CMD`. So, you need to run `sgadmin_demo.sh`, but you need to wait for elasticsearch first. Create a `start.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
elasticsearch
sleep 15
sgadmin_demo.sh
```

Now, add your script to your image and run it on `CMD`:

```
FROM: ...
...
COPY start.sh /tmp/start.sh
CMD ["/tmp/start.sh"]
```

Now it should be executed once you start a container. Don't forget to build :)